Choix pour « … autres parts » ou « … autre part » ?
Dans cette phrase :
« Action interdite sur l'organe thymus, prudence autres parts. »
"… autres parts" remplace "… sur les autres organes", pour éviter une répétition.
Le pluriel est-il correct ?

Je dirais que c'est ce raccoursissement que l'on voit souvent en français technique. prudence [en ce qui concerne] les autres parts.

"Prudence en ce qui concerne les autres parts" does not really make sense. It's quite unlikely that "parts" in the plural is appropriate here. See jlliagre's answer instead.

La forme qui s'impose est autre part, qui est invariable.
On aurait pu dire prudence ailleurs, qui est donné comme (seul?) synonyme d'autre part.
Possibles aussi:

[...], prudence pour le reste (@graffito)
[...], prudence pour les autres [organes] (@Personne)
Action interdite sur le thymus, la prudence est de mise dans les autres cas.


Belle trouvaille : les dicos consultés font une entrée de l'expression au singulier et ajoutent le « d' » dans leur exemple synonyme de « par ailleurs », sans signifier l'invariabilité. +1 (et un autre +1 ‘imaginaire’ pour la rapidité :-)

Ou prudence pour le reste.

Ou prudence pour les autres [organes]
